# How to move/change direction of an object with android animation?

Tags: android, animation

i'm trying to make a simple "ping-pong" application in android, but i'm unable to find a mode to repeat the basic animation like

```
TranslateAnimation(fromX,toX,fromY,toY);
```

I want to make a ball bouncing on the border of screen, how can i dynamically change the direction?

Comment: i have updated the answer please check and reply..if it works.. @Gianluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for a ping-pong game I would strongly suggest you to use a custom View for rendering. That being said, what you can do is create your `Animation` instance programmatically so that you can compute x and y values. 
Let's say you have a layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#ffff0000" />

</FrameLayout>
```

So you're going to animate that View up and down

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Animation.AnimationListener {

    private lateinit var view: View
    private var viewX = 0f
    private var viewY = 0f
    private var dstX = 0f
    private var dstY = 0f

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        view = findViewById(R.id.view)
        startViewAnimation()
    }

    private fun startViewAnimation(){
        dstX = Random().nextFloat()
        dstY = if (viewY == 1f) 0f else 1f

        val animation = TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, viewX,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, dstX,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, viewY,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, dstY
        )
        animation.duration = 1000L
        animation.setAnimationListener(this)
        animation.fillAfter = true
        view.startAnimation(animation)
    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
        viewX = dstX
        viewY = dstY
        startViewAnimation()
    }

    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) = Unit
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) = Unit

}
```

The `y` coordinate is alternating between 0 and 1, because the ball (well the square) is going up and down up and down. The `x` is just a random value.

`x` and `y` values are a percentage of the parent's size.

When the animation ends, you simply start a new one with new destination coordinates.

Comment: thank for the answer, but the class mainactivity was wrote on wich language? I'm using android studio and this isn't java. sorry for the ignorance :(

Comment: No worries, that's Kotlin, it is fully supported in Android Studio 3. It's much much better than java, I would suggest you to give it a try. If you have problems running my sample let me know, I'll update it to java

Comment: thanks for the advise about kotlin, but for now i'll use java to make my prof happy ahahah. I have one last question, what is the pourpose of animation.setAnimationListener(this) ?

Comment: The animation listener is an interface that has 3 methods (onAnimationStart, onAnimationRepeat, onAnimationEnd). If you set the listener to the animation, the respective methods are called so that you can do something. For instance in our case, when the animation finishes, onAnimationEnd is called and we have the possibility to compute new coordinates and start a new animation